# Why does Keras gives me different results between model.evaluate, model.predicts & model.fit?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm working on a project with a resnet50 based dual output model. One output is for the regression task and the second output is for a classification task.

My main question is about the model evaluation. During the training, I achieve pretty good results on both ouputs on the validation set:
- Combined loss = 0.32507268732786176
- Val accuracy = 0.97375
- Val MSE: 4.1454763

The model.evaluate gives me the following results on the same set:
- Combined loss = 0.33064378452301024
- Val accuracy  = 0.976
- Val MSE       = 1.2375486

The model.predict gives me totally differents result (I use scikit-learn to compute the metrics):
- Val accuracy = 0.45875
- Val MSE: 43.555958365743805
These last values changes at each predict execution.

I work on TF2.0.
Here is my code:

```py
valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, 
                                            directory=PATH, 
                                            x_col="X", 
                                            y_col=["yReg","yCls"],  
                                            class_mode="multi_output", 
                                            target_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE), 
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            subset="validation",
                                            shuffle=False,
                                            workers = 0)
def generate_data_generator(generator, train=True):
    while True:
        Xi, yi = train_generator.next()
        y2 = []
        for e in yi[1]:
            y2.append(to_categorical(e, 7))
        y2 = np.array(y2)
        if train: # Augmentation for training only
            Xi = Xi.astype('uint8')
            Xi_aug = seq(images=Xi) # imgaug lib needs uint8
            Xi_aug = Xi_aug.astype('float32')
            Xi_aug = preprocess_input(Xi_aug) # resnet50 preprocessing
            yield Xi_aug, [yi[0], y2]
        else: # Validation
            yield preprocess_input(Xi), [yi[0], y2]


model.fit_generator(generator=generate_data_generator(train_generator, True),
    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
    validation_data=generate_data_generator(valid_generator, False),
    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
    verbose=1, 
    epochs=50, 
    callbacks=[checkpoint, tfBoard],
    )
```

```py
evalu = model.evaluate_generator(generate_data_generator(valid_generator, False), steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID)
print(model.metrics_names)
print(evalu)
```

```py
preds = model.predict_generator(generate_data_generator(valid_generator, False), steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID, workers = 0)
labels = valid_generator.labels

print("MSE error:", me.mean_squared_error(labels[0], preds[0]))
print("Accuracy:", me.accuracy_score(labels[1], preds[1].argmax(axis=1)))
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: are you fitting on CPU or GPU?

Comment: On a single GPU

Comment: I am having the same problem but I just read that GPU might cause some degree of randomnes. I'm testing it right now if I get anything interesting I get back to you.

Answer (score 6):

You are calculating accuracy using just one data point `labels[1], preds[1]` instead of all data points. You need to compute accuracy considering all data points to compare the result with `model.evaluate_generator`. Also you have computed `MSE` on `labels[0], preds[0]` data points but accuracy on `labels[1], preds[1]` data points. Consider all the data points in both the cases.

Below is an example of binary classification where I am not doing any data augmentation for validation data. You can build the validation generator without Augmentation and set `shuffle=False` to generate same batch of data every time, thus you will get same result for `model.evaluate_generator`and `model.predict_generator`.

**Validation Generator -**

```
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our validation data

val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              shuffle=False,
                                                              seed=10,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='binary')
```

**Below are the results for accuracy which all match** -

**model.fit_generator**

```
history = model.fit_generator(
          train_data_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=total_train // batch_size,
          epochs=5,
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
          validation_steps=total_val // batch_size)
```

Output -

```
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/5
20/20 [==============================] - 27s 1s/step - loss: 0.8691 - accuracy: 0.4995 - val_loss: 0.6850 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/5
20/20 [==============================] - 26s 1s/step - loss: 0.6909 - accuracy: 0.5145 - val_loss: 0.6880 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/5
20/20 [==============================] - 26s 1s/step - loss: 0.6682 - accuracy: 0.5345 - val_loss: 0.6446 - val_accuracy: 0.6320
Epoch 4/5
20/20 [==============================] - 26s 1s/step - loss: 0.6245 - accuracy: 0.6180 - val_loss: 0.6214 - val_accuracy: 0.5920
Epoch 5/5
20/20 [==============================] - 27s 1s/step - loss: 0.5696 - accuracy: 0.6795 - val_loss: 0.6468 - val_accuracy: 0.6270
```

**model.evaluate_generator**

```
evalu = model.evaluate_generator(val_data_gen)
print(model.metrics_names)
print(evalu)
```

Output -

```
['loss', 'accuracy']
[0.646793782711029, 0.6269999742507935]
```

**model.predict_generator**

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, accuracy_score
preds = model.predict_generator(val_data_gen)
y_pred = tf.where(preds<=0.5,0,1)

labels = val_data_gen.labels
y_true = labels

# confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

Output -

```
Accuracy: 0.627
```

**Complete Code for your reference -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs.zip', origin=_URL, extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'cats_and_dogs_filtered')

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')  # directory with our training cat pictures
train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')  # directory with our training dog pictures
validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')  # directory with our validation cat pictures
validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')  # directory with our validation dog pictures

num_cats_tr = len(os.listdir(train_cats_dir))
num_dogs_tr = len(os.listdir(train_dogs_dir))

num_cats_val = len(os.listdir(validation_cats_dir))
num_dogs_val = len(os.listdir(validation_dogs_dir))

total_train = num_cats_tr + num_dogs_tr
total_val = num_cats_val + num_dogs_val

batch_size = 100
epochs = 5
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,brightness_range=[0.5,1.5]) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='binary')

val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              shuffle=False,
                                                              seed=10,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", 
          loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
          train_data_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=total_train // batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
          validation_steps=total_val // batch_size)

evalu = model.evaluate_generator(val_data_gen, steps=total_val // batch_size)
print(model.metrics_names)
print(evalu)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, accuracy_score
#val_data_gen.reset()
preds = model.predict_generator(val_data_gen, steps=total_val // batch_size)
y_pred = tf.where(preds<=0.5,0,1)

labels = val_data_gen.labels
y_true = labels

test_labels = []

for i in range(0,10):
    test_labels.extend(np.array(val_data_gen[i][1]))

# confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy_score(test_labels, y_pred))
```

Also keep in mind, `fit_generator`, `evaluate_generator` and `predict_generator` FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Please use Model.fit, Model.evaluate and Model.predict respectively, which supports generators.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @yannivain - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: When you do `tf.where(preds<=0.5,0,1)` after the predict step, does tf does this operation automatically when perform evaluation or during training to give results on loss and other metrics?

Comment: excuse me does number of epochs affect in this problem as my training dataset is around 87000 and testing is 45000 images and i used one epoch but got different values with same output –

Comment: I have just skimmed through your answer paying attention to code snippets only and paid for it. You have mentioned shuffle=False for the test data generator. And this was the crucial option that prevented my .evaluate and .predict metrics to be coherent. Unfortunately I had to discover this myself. :) Thank you for your answer.